# How to import html data to MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have HTML source and want to import specific tags from the HTML source to database-table " MySql " by using C#.
any suggestion would be great.

Comment: insert a string..?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very abroad and we need some enlightment on your question, first off:

- Do you have a database yet?
- Do you have a connection with that database?
- Have you set up a way to fire queries at that database?
- Have you created a user that is allowed to fire queries at the database?
- Why not save every unique column as a column in the database? pasting plain HTML into a database isn't really good practise.

Create a table named test_table with the column ID with an auto increment and a column `data` with the type longtext.

for the query:

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`data`) VALUES ('<a>someHTML code</a>')
```